# nginx: post doesn't work when using proxy forwarding

Tags: nginx, post, nginx-location

Try to figure out a correct nginx configuration so that it can work with some prefix in url.

Previously working with the followings.

1. nginx conf

   ```
   location / {
           client_max_body_size 30M;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
           proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:3000/;
           proxy_redirect off;
   }
   ```

Basically it redirects to a docker container with port 3000.

2. html form

   < form id="request_form" action="/post_handler?request=fetch" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
3. ajax for the submit

   event.preventDefault();

   var form = document.getElementById('request_form'),
     form_data = new FormData(form),
     form_url = '/' + $('#' + request + '_form')[0].action.split('/').pop();

   $.ajax({
     url: form_url,
     type: 'POST',
     data: form_data,
     dataType: 'json',
     encode: true,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false
   })
4. backend route

   router.post('/post_handler', function(request, response) {

Everything works at this point. Now I need to set up another docker container on the same machine. So I think maybe I should use different URL to differentiate them.

nginx conf

```
    location /service1 {
            client_max_body_size 30M;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:3000/;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

I still can get the right page. But I don't know how to get it right for the post url. This is what I tried.

```
var form = document.getElementById('request_form'),
  form_data = new FormData(form),
  form_url = '/service1/' + $('#' + request + '_form')[0].action.split('/').pop();
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Try: `location /service1/`

Comment: @RichardSmith, yes, it works, thanks for the help!